# PDE models in life and social sciences

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I wanted to know if there are models based on diffusion-convection PDEs in the social sciences, life-sciences, health & public policy, etc.

I would assume that phenomena like the spread of diseases/species/populations/genes/memes, transport of drugs/chemicals within organisms, etc, could be modeled using some variation of parabolic-hyperbolic PDEs ?

I know that spatio-temporal relationships are commonly studied using graphical models ( which are more empirical / data-driven ) - but is there theory / work on modeling these phenomena from a first-principles perspective ?

If so, I would appreciate if you could point me to some literature on the use of these models in these fields ? Review / survey papers would be especially appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, so did you find some pde models in that field? especially in social science? and if so could you pls let me know? thx!